# Using rules to grant new role upon visiting page

Tags: rules

Using the modules "rules" and "rules linkevent" I am trying to get drupal to automatically assign a new role to the user upon visiting a certain page.

I've written it like this/entered the following values and selected these options:

-

Events Event
levelup2 was accessed

-

Conditions Elements

User has role(s)
Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: authenticated user

-

Actions Elements

Add user role
Parameter: User: [site:current-user], Roles: Level 2

---

What am I doing wrong or how could I alternatively make the user accessing the page, reading the page or another trigger I can make be granted a new role?

I have tried searching the net but have found no answers. 
Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you put that rule statements here ?

Comment: What do you mean? I put what the info in my post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Rules Path](https://drupal.org/project/pathrules) and [Rules URL Argument](https://drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) modules trigger events based on the current URL being viewed.

You could also use the [Rules Link](https://drupal.org/project/rules_link) module to generate a custom link that will trigger your rules. The catch here is that this specific link must be clicked to access the page and the user I believe must be signed in.

If you need fine tuned control over when the Rules event is triggered you could even [implement your own Rules Event](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_event_info/7).

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Sadly I still can't seem  to get it right.

I set the event to "url" was visited. 

I set the path (in conditions) to "check url" and set it to the given page. 

I set the action to "grant role" 

Yet it does not seem to work?

Comment: You may need to use the system path instead of an alias. I've also added https://drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument to the answer above. :)

Comment: Still can't get it to work. I've tried button fields.. I've tried all the modules you suggest but yet I can't seem to find a way to activate a trigger that is only placed on one specific node. Neither of the sites work with URL (Neither custom page nor a node). I think I might be better off asking someone to write the necessary code for a new custom module.. This is horrible o.O Have spent +10 hours on this single problem now

Comment: I will mark this post as answered simply because it should answer most other users questions in relation to this. I might just be an idiot for not getting it to work

Answer (score 0):

You could use page manager with the rules bonus pack to achieve what you want. 
Watch this screen cast: http://vimeo.com/25153525